# Locking Project

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, security

I need to guide me to lock my project against "unauthorized use" with a certain registration key which I will send it personally.

I also want to inform me if this lock method can break it with reverse engineer method.

I use visual basic for my project in visual studio 2010.

Comment: What do you mean by "lock" your project?  Do you mean to not allow other users to edit its files?

Comment: I mean to secure my project by an illegal use "Unauthrized" use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no general case method of preventing someone from reverse engineering your application. It is code, and therefore it is possible to analyze. This is exacerbated by tools such as Reflector, which take a .NET assembly and dump out a complete Visual Studio solution capable of building the given .NET assembly. A malicious user could simply dump your assembly, remove the licensing bits, and then recompile the assembly.

However, you can use a code obfuscation tool (i.e. [Dotfuscator](http://preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview) (disclaimer: PreEmptive Solutions is my employer)) to make your code confusing enough that it's extremely difficult to figure out where exactly the registration bits are located.

That said, merely obfuscating the code still doesn't protect you the way you're trying to be protected, because you want to embed a secret (that is, the registration code) in the binary. Code obfuscators can help with this (i.e. string encryption), but this is in general a weak area -- your program has to get the constant in cleartext at some point, therefore the method to get the cleartext must exist in your program somewhere. After all, there are cracks and things for Windows and pretty much every video game on the planet, despite the millions companies like Sony spend on anti-copying technology.

Comment: Thank you very much But you make my days BLACK :) because you have right in all of the above. Never the less I will use the obfuscator from @alliswell and see what i can do about (of course i have a copy from my project). Thats the one part of my question, the other is how to make a product key and i can use it? Is there any certain method or I have to use my imagination?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to secure your project from re-engineering and reading then,

Try [obfuscation](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/15/free-net-obfuscation-tools/) for securing your application at CERTAIN level.

Product Key,

Before few months back our team was discussing about

"How to secure our Product from Illegal Copying,ReEng etc"

Following are the conclusions,

1. for re-eng - Obfuscation
2. Copying - Decided to create a Product key based on Some Client + Other Details(Harddisk#+BIOS#) and we maintained the separate database for it.

So its upto you,I mean how much you want to secure your application. 
Since you mentioned that you will be separately sending product key then it can be any combination like CustomerName+Date etc.

Also some obfuscation tool provide the way to generate product key, don't remember the name.

Comment: thank you very much for your interest in my issue. Yes it is the truth that I'm co-operating with a weasel and i want to protect my job from him. Thats why i want to find the best way for it. The product key which giving me from some obfuscations not cover me. So Please try to assist me as much as you can do, guiding me to this issue. Is there any posibility to mail me or not?

Comment: And where do you stuck? Product key or Obfuscation.

Comment: For the moment i haven't stuck anywhere but i'm collecting information's of how i will produce a "Product Key"